# placing divs in same line

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 divs. One with N number of squares and another div with 1 square. I want that all squares should be inlined. i.e., the squares of div of **"section-loaded"** come in 3 lines and half of 4th line, one after the other, then the square of **"section-toload"** should come in the same 4th line and not down below. Here is the fiddle -

http://jsfiddle.net/UPA4V/

```
<div class="fix_width650px">
    <div class="section-loaded">
        <div class = "square"></div>
        <div class = "square"></div>
        <div class = "square"></div>
        <div class = "square"></div>
        .
        .
        .
    </div>

    <div class="section-toload">
        <div class = "square"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS-

```
.square{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.section-loaded{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;

}

.section-toload{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;

}
```

Comment: can you show image if possible, of what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: in my answer you can try adding more sqare in section_loaded, it'll work fine

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UPA4V/6/

Comment: @vepasto : where is padding in your fiddle ??

Comment: @ITppl : Maybe you could change it as margin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

Live demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/eGSvn/3/)

**HTML**

```
    <div class="fix_width650px">
        <div class="section-loaded">
            <div class = "square"></div>
            <div class = "square"></div>
            <div class = "square"></div>
            <div class = "square"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="section-toload">
            <div class = "square sqgreen"></div>
            <div class = "square sqgreen"></div>
            <div class = "square sqgreen"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .square{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 5px !important;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    border:2px dotted red;
    margin:5px;
}

.sqgreen{
    border:4px dotted green !important;
}

.fix_width650px
{
    width:650px;
}
```

Comment: Lol... i thought you wanted them fluid, not static :D

Answer (score 2):

It would work if you instead setting sections as float, set squares as float.

only css you need:

> .square{ 
>      width: 150px; 
>      height: 150px; 
>      float:left; 
>   }

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that.
As 'setion-loaded' is taking more than 1 line, that means the width of this section becomes 100% and whatever the next is goes on new line i.e. 'section-toload' goes on new line.

What you can do is have all squares in one section and apply extra class 'loaded' if they are loaded and the class 'toload' of they are to be loaded.

```
    <div class="section">
      <div class="square loaded"></div>
      <div class="square loaded"></div>
      <div class="square loaded"></div>
      <div class="square loaded"></div>
      ...
      ...
      ...
      <div class="square toload"></div> 
    </div>
```

CSS -

```
   .square {
      float: left;
      width: 150px;
      /** other styles **/  
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't, because the shape of the `section-loaded box` will always be rectangular, while you want to inject your `section-toload square` inside it, in an arbitrary position.

You can dot it with squares only, or if you need sections, encapsulate each square in one section, like this:

**Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2QLmJ/**

HTML

```
<div class="fix_width650px">
    <div class="section loaded">
        <div class = "square"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="section loaded">
        <div class = "square"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="section loaded">
        <div class = "square"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="section loaded">
        <div class = "square"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="section toload">
        <div class = "square"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    .square{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.toload .square{
    border: 1px solid red;    
}

.section{
    margin: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want something like this .
[image]

```
.square
{

width: 150px;
height: 150px;
padding: 5px;
text-align: center;
float:left;
position: relative;
border:1px solid red;
}

.section-loaded{
display: block;
width:486px;
float: left;
}

.section-toload{
display: block;
float: left;
position:absolute;
overflow: hidden;
}


<div class="fix_width650px" style="height:326px;">
<div class="section-loaded">
<div class = "square">square1</div>
<div class = "square">square2</div>
<div class = "square">square3</div>
<div class = "square">square4</div>
</div>


</div>
<div class="section-toload"  style="position :relative;">
<div class = "square">section-toload</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float-left` from both the divs and add `display:table-cell` and `vertical-align:bottom`

```
.section-loaded{
    display: table-cell;

}

.section-toload{
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align:bottom

}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UPA4V/2/)**